# Are questions that can only be answered by writing a whole manual on-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Is a question of the form "how can I do *X* with *some software that does X*", such as [*how to debug c code using gdb*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957698/how-to-debug-c-code-using-gdb), on topic? I would assume such a question to be "too broad", since an acceptable answer would be rather extensive. On top of that, the internet may be full of resources that explain in detail how to use such a tool. On the other hand, at the time of writing I am the only one who has voted to close that question as "too broad". I am eccentric in my close voting?

Comment: I concur with your reasoning.  In addition, it's somewhat _gauche_ to ask others to edit his answer without making it CW.

Comment: I can't imagine that too many people would disagree with your assessment. The only good explanation is that there are 11.1k entries waiting in the close review queue. Once people take a look at it, you'll get the necessary votes quickly. As you saw once you posted it here. I was already too late to cast one of the 4 necessary votes...

Comment: And it has been nominated for reopening as well, so there appears to be some controversy. There already are lists of external resources for other topics; why not add them to this one?

Comment: It now has -3 total votes and is thus potentially deletable.

Comment: Deleted now....

Comment: Too bad. I don't know about this particular execution (gdb is not my area) but "how to debug with gdb" *is* a FAQ and also frequently recommended. Could it have been made a [community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)?

Comment: @Jongware I am not sure what the point of that would be, given that there is extensive documentation out there already. Also, it doesn't matter if something is an FAQ, if the Q is off-topic.

Comment: Debugging is an unavoidable step in software development, just like writing code and testing.  Asking how to use a debugger tool is like asking 'How to write programs in GCC', which I assume would be closed as too broad.

Comment: @juanchopanza: OK, that was a bad idea from my side. However looking at your post it seems like you are overemphasizing, this topic could have been discussed on chat rooms.
There exists around 11K post in close review queue, are you suggesting everyone to put a post here for each entry explaining why it should be closed?

Comment: @Ani No, I am not suggesting any such thing. I wanted to know if the question was off-topic, like I believed it to be. I still have no answer here, which is disappointing.

Comment: Why delete the question so early and not give the OP the chance to become more specific in his question?

Comment: Also note that SO already has some answers which read like a chapter of a book, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/538238/480982

Comment: @juanchopanza: What answer are you expecting? You already know that question is "off-topic" that's why you flag it and then you also posted the link on your post, so that everyone can flag it quickly(and write harsh comments). I'm very displeased to see someone commented as "Let's get one more down-vote so we can delete this mess now." it was deleted later(I have the snapshot of it).

Comment: @All: I respect everyone on SO, if you all find that my idea doesn't add any value and this post should be deleted, then I welcome your decision.

Comment: @Ani I was expecting "yes, it is off-topic, obviously" or "no, it is not off topic because A, B and C".

Comment: @ThomasW.: I would not say "like a chapter of a book", it's barely 5 pages (on my screen). It may be a long answer, but it does not appear to be excessive, and at least to me does not feel overly broad (it is focused on one particular mechanism). On the other hand, the use of a debugger is extremely vast: multiple concepts, multiple commands, etc...

Comment: @ThomasW. Note that there is not necessarily anything wrong with long answers per se (some of the better answers on SO are necessarily long.) The issue here is about the questions.

Comment: self-answered questions like that look like a symptom of _[tag wiki blindness](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120588/165773)_

Comment: I don't love the gdb question, but I've liked questions that did not admit a short answer but 1) were still narrow enough that a few screenfulls of text could shed light on them, and 2) weren't better answered by reading the manual. So, not every broad-ish question is too broad. In the Go tag where I hang out, I've liked questions about how you structure packages and how you'd choose between methods and functions or pointers and values. The .NET Dispose answer above seems like a particularly epic example of a question that pushes the bounds but is worth having on the site.

Comment: @twotwotwo Right. I am not asking about that kind of question. I am asking about questions where any answer other than the manual would be considerably incomplete.

Comment: Yep, I didn't mean to sound argumentative if I did (like I say, I don't like the `gdb` question); the thread just seemed to have started talking about broad questions and answers generally. I agree with the top-voted answer and your vote.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Are questions that can only be answered by writing a whole manual on-topic?

This is explicitly addressed [by the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) (practically to the letter):

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

"*How do I use GDB?*" is not a reasonable question for Stack Overflow because it doesn't identify a specific point of concern. In particular, that question-post didn't ask a question; I think if it had, the question would have been obviously too vague to be on-topic, e.g. "*What are some things GDB can do?*"

If you're trying to use a particular feature of GDB and can't make it operate as described in the manual, *that's* on-topic.

Answer (score -3):

IMHO, your question relies on a premise that needs to be examined more closely, namely: **there are questions that can only be answered by writing a whole manual**.

Is that true?  I have no idea.  It seems false to me, though, because you can always omit detail.  Conversely, I bet the amount of detail that you could go into to answer even seemingly simple questions could get massive.

You wrote **the internet may be full of resources that explain in detail how to use such a tool** later on.  So what?  The internet's probably already answered pretty much every question on SO.  But I bet there's still room for another answer, perhaps providing a different point of view or a new insight.

Also, let's keep in mind that it's perfectly possible (and useful) to answer questions in multiple, different ways.  There can be a useful answer of 5 words, another of 50 words, another of 500 words, another of 5000 words, and another of 50000 words.  These answers may be useful to different groups of people in different ways.

I suppose we could also talk about a question's propensity to attract long answers.  But I don't see the point, because that seems super difficult to judge correctly.  I bet it would be subjective, and lead to arguments.  I can't imagine anything more boring to argue about.

Finally, just so any readers know where I'm coming from -- I like long answers and wish there were more of them.  In my experience, they're usually filled with tons of insight, experience, and tips.  I don't want to do anything that discourages people from writing great answers.

Comment: Note that, although manuals tend to be long, this question is not about SO questions that require *long answers*, not about the merit of said answers. I am aware that some of the better answers on the site are long, but they rarely deal with overly broad questions.

Comment: @juanchopanza did you read my post?  I am also talking about questions, however, I am questioning your premises.

Comment: @juanchopanza unrelated, but there seems to be a typo in your comment which makes it hard to parse.

Comment: Yes, I read the post. The clarification is not related to your first point, which is a valid one. As for the typo, yes, I meant "this question is not about SO questions that require long answers, **nor** about the merit of said answers..."

Comment: @juanchopanza hmm, you're saying that you think that part of my post is not relevant to your question?  I respect your opinion, but am going to have to disagree with you there.

Answer (score -4):

It's sometimes the case that a question's topic is specific but requires an extensive answer.

If you have good knowledge of the topic and could potentially give an extensive answer, you might instead summarize what an extensive answer would contain and also add reference links to the details of the extensive answer.

A common example occurs when dealing with the web. The questioner asks something specific and scoped like this:

> My browser throws a cross-domain security error with my specific code below. 
>   How can I fix that?

The answer is specific in scope but too extensive for a Stackoverflow answer. The answer would require configuring their web server and including client-side script to pass security concerns.

Perhaps a good summarized answer might be:

> A full answer to your question would be more extensive than a
>   Stackoverflow answer allows, but here is a summary of what you need to
>   do and links to help you learn more details...*summary & links here*

Comment: When an acceptable answer is beyond the scope of what is appropriate for an SO answer the correct course of action is to close the question as too broad, not to post a low quality answer explaining why you can't post a quality answer.

Comment: @Servy I agree that if an acceptable answer is truly beyond SO scope then the question would therefore be too broad, too.  However, a summary answer + links to more learning might not be too broad. And certainly a summary answer need not be "low quality"!

Comment: I've written some long answers. But I've also had cases where clearly, despite being a good question that might be useful to lots of people without a good tutorial out there, it still wasn't a good SO question, like "How do I do a thread pool?" (too broad) or "Which of Tkinter's validation methods is better?" (too subjective). So what do you do if you still want to help the asker? Write a blog post, add a link to it in a comment, along with an explanation as to why the question wasn't a good fit for SO, and vote to close the question.

Comment: @abarnert. Yes, I do similarly...If the question is too broad I often put links to tutorials/blogs in the comments of the question without answering the question.

Comment: @abarnert That's certainly an acceptable course of action.

Comment: @markE And yet your answer here is advocating answering the question instead.  And to your earlier point SO has in fact come to the consensus that link only answers *aren't* quality answers here.  You shouldn't be posting an answer just to link to a tutorial/blog; an answer should *answer the question* rather than telling the reader where to find the answer, and that clearly can't be done here.

Comment: @Servy I'm certainly not advocating link-only answers!  Link-only responses, if given, belong in a comment to the question.  My opinion is that (1) if the question is good & future visitors to SO might have the same question, (2) if the answerer has good knowledge of a full & proper answer (3) if the full answer would be lengthier than SO desires, (4) ...then...a SUMMARY ANSWER plus links containing additional learning resources is useful to those future visitors.  This summary+learning resources answer is commonly given by IT managers to junior coders--and this type of answer works well.

Comment: @markE So then when a really broad question is asked you're advocating people provide an incomplete answer that doesn't actually answer the question?  "Go read a tutorial on the subject" is an entirely appropriate response for a manager to tell a new programmer, but it's not an appropriate answer for an SO question.  On SO the appropriate response is to close the question as "Too Broad".

Comment: @Servy. Kindly don't put words in my mouth :-) If a question is too broad...close it!  I talk here about a well scoped question whose *full answer* is would be valuable but is too lengthy for the SO format.  **A proven and useful tool for IT managers is to answer junior coder's questions with a useful summary of what needs to be done plus point them towards additional learning resources.**  YES, I advocate "saving-not-discarding" good questions with summary+learning resource answers.

Comment: @markE So you think a question that requires an entire manual as an answer is a well scoped question?  Really?  You're sticking to that?  The question here provided the *textbook definition* of too broad, and your response to that was to say to provide an incomplete answer since the full answer would be too lengthy.  That's *not* appropriate; and the guidelines are very clear on this.  When a complete answer cannot be given due to its scope, the question should be closed as too broad.  It should *not* be given an incomplete answer.

Comment: @Servy Kindly s-t-o-p putting words in my mouth! Questions that are too broad should be closed...period...! I address well scoped questions whose **answers**, if posted in full, would be lengthy.  My answer hypothesizes a well scoped question that requires a lengthy answer. And I propose that an appropriate answer in such situations is a summary+learning links. I have experience & affirm that this type of answer works well for future junior coders who need the answer.  Such an answer furthers the SO purpose of being useful to future visitors who may have the same good and well scoped question.

Comment: @markE So you're asserting that your answer is unrelated to the meta question here because you're not talking about the actual situation that's described?  The OP is asking what to do when a question is too broad.  If you're responding to, "What should I do when I find a question that's too broad?" with, "If the question isn't too broad you should answer it" then how is that helpful in the slightest?

Comment: If a question is well scoped *then you shouldn't be summarizing an answer at all, you should be providing a complete answer*.  If you *can't* provide a complete answer then that is the *definition* of "too broad".  So advocating that people answer a question that they can't provide a complete answer to is advocating that people answer questions that are too broad.  Saying that you aren't advocating answering questions that are too broad while advocating answering questions that meet the exact definition of "too broad" isn't me putting words in your mouth; it's you contradicting yourself.

Comment: @Servy. I advocate that a good summary plus learning material can provide a "complete" answer to a well scoped question. If you feel that my answer doesn't address the question posed then you may have a point.  The question is "Are questions that can only be answered by writing a whole manual on-topic?" and I pose that "how can I do X with some software that does X" might be a good and scoped question (if not, close that question).  If the question is good and scoped, I propose we use it as a resource for future visitors rather than dumping it because p-a-r-t of the answer is a learning link.

Comment: @markE The answer should be able to answer the question without requiring the reader to read the entirety of the link.  If the answer, without the link, doesn't provide a complete answer to the question then the answer is not appropriate.  The inclusion of a bit of text beyond the link doesn't automatically make the answer acceptable; if the answer is completely dependent on the user following the link to actually get their question answered, then the answer isn't an acceptable answer.  **By definition**, if a question is going to require a manual to answer then it is not reasonably scoped.

Comment: @Servy The extreme of your philosophy is that links should never be allowed on SO answers and that all answers should be complete code suitable for the questioner to plug into their project to solve their question.  The extreme of my philosophy is a link only answer. I'm proposing that a complete summary plus links answer falls in the acceptably between these 2 extremes.

Comment: @Servy I object to your phrase "a bit of text". What I propose is a **complete summary** of the full answer. And again(!)...if a QUESTION is too broad in scope then let's close it!  The interesting point of juanchopanza's question is whether an answer can ever be too broad--not whether a question can be too broad (many SO questions are too broad).

Comment: @markE An answer on the site should not be *defendant* on a link.  Every single answer should answer the question even without the link.  That is the site's policy.  It's not [just] my position.  If your answer doesn't answer the question without following a link it contains then it's not an acceptable answer.  That has nothing to do with whether or not the question contains code, or whether or not that code can be copy-pasted by the reader.

Comment: @markE A summary can never be complete.  By definition.  The literal *definition* of a summary requires it to not be complete.  If it were, it would be paraphrasing.  If summarizing the content of a link is a complete answer to the question, then there doesn't even need to be a link at all, someone could just provide a paragraph or two answer with no link that answers the question.  The whole premise of this meta question is that the question *cannot* be answered with just a few paragraph; it would take a whole manual.

Comment: @Servy Then let's ban links (sarcastism only). I suggest many, many great SO answers do not provide specific code to solve the questioners needs, but rather describe steps the questioner must follow to solve their problem.  In other words, many great answers summarize the steps required. A "SUM"-mary gives a **complete overview of an answer with the promise that more details will expand that summary**.  The links provide the details that fill that promise.  If the questioner had more knowledge they could answer their question with just the summary. The links fill an OP's unknown knowledge gap.

Comment: @markE I never said that every good SO answer needs to provide code; I never said there was anything wrong with an answer that explains how to solve a problem instead of providing the exact code to solve the problem.  You seem to be incorrectly conflating *summarize* with *explain*.  They are not the same thing, at all.  If you are going to explain how to solve a problem then the answer needs to be a *complete* explanation.  That doesn't necessarily mean code, but it means enough information to answer the question.  A summary is an *incomplete* explanation.

Comment: @markE As I've said probably half a dozen times now, an answer on this site needs to be a *complete* answer.  If your answer to a question requires the reader to follow a link and read a bunch of content there to actually get an answer to their question then your answer didn't answer the question; it was incomplete.

Comment: @Servy. I do understand and I appreciate your point.  BTW, I also appreciate our discussion--you have a mind well worth conversing with :-).  Actual questions are often black and white, but are sometimes gray. My philosophy differs with yours only in the gray area.  I believe if a question is well scoped but the answer requires the questioner to learn beyond an answer then an answer that completely summarizes the answer and points them to an expanded answer through learning, then that answer is valuable to future viewers of SO. Maybe we can agree if I replace "summary" with "explain". GottaGo!

Comment: @markE My entire premise is that if you can't adequately answer a question it's *not* okay to just provide an incomplete answer that doesn't actually answer the question and post it as an answer.  If you can't provide a *complete* answer that adequately explains how to solve the problem then then question is Too Broad and it needs to be closed.  If you want to point someone to a tutorial in a comment on such a question, you're more than welcome to, but posting incomplete answers to questions that are too broad *is not acceptable*.

Comment: Once again you're starting out with the premise that the question cannot be adequately answered in the scope of an SO answer and yet you're calling it "well scoped".  **By definition** if you cannot provide a complete answer to the question in an SO answer then the question isn't "well scoped".  It is the literal definition of not being well scoped.  If the question is well scoped than you can provide a complete answer in just a few paragraphs and you don't need to link anywhere else at all.  You're trying to literally re-define "too broad" as "reasonably scoped".

Comment: IMHO, `Summary !== incomplete`.  `Summary === complete but summarized explanation`.